# How to combine many rows into single text?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to grouping phone number to the same section like this :

```
section | phone
   1    | 1001
   1    | 1002
   2    | 1201
   2    | 1202
```

and grouping them in like this :

```
section | phone
   1    | 1001, 1002
   2    | 1201, 1202
```

but i don't know syntax to groping them to that.

This code i do

```
var entgr = (from fx in MainOnline.MA_TelUsers
             where fx.TE_SectionID != null
             group fx by fx.TE_SectionID into id
             from ids in id.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new 
             { 
                  Section = ids.TE_SectionID,
                  TelPhone = ids.TE_Phone                                         
             });
```

How I grouping that and use it to join other table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var entgr = (from fx in ph
                         group fx by fx.SectionId.ToString() into id
                         select new
                         {
                             Section = id.Key,
                             TelPhone = string.Join(", ",id.Select(s => s.PhoneNumber.ToString()))
                         });
```

Comment: Thank you. I  can do it now.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
var entgr = (from fx in MainOnline.MA_TelUsers
                 where fx.TE_SectionID != null
                 group fx by fx.TE_SectionID into ids
                           select new
                           {
 Section = ids.TE_SectionID,
                      TelPhone =ids.Aggregate((a, b) => 
                                       new {TelPhone = (a.TelPhone + ", " + b.TelPhone ) }).TelPhone 

                           });
```

Comment: It can't work. It don't know ls in TelPhone = ids.Intersect(ls.Select(t => t.TE_Phone))

Comment: It can't work. It can't convert string to char in new TelPhone it's char does't have reference. Are u use version ref of them ?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

See this link. If you want to it do it in single linq query then that I hope not possible.

But at evaluation time you can do like this

```
var ph = new List<Phone>();
            ph.Add(new Phone() { SectionId = 1, PhoneNumber = 1001 });
            ph.Add(new Phone() { SectionId = 1, PhoneNumber = 1002 });
            ph.Add(new Phone() { SectionId = 2, PhoneNumber = 1201 });
            ph.Add(new Phone() { SectionId = 2, PhoneNumber = 1202 });

            var results = ph.GroupBy(i => i.SectionId).Select(i=> new {i.Key, i});
            foreach (var phone in results)
            {
                int section = phone.Key;
                string phoneNos = string.Join(",",phone.i.Select(i=>i.PhoneNumber));
            }
```

Comment: I think this can be convert into a query, without foreach